# How to parse Json files using Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

Still on this issue, and I know this is an old post, but I'm also struggling to get C# to parse JSON.

I'm using Unity 2018.2.8f1, and VS 2019 (I also tried on VS 2017).

Here is my Json file (a really really simple one):

```
{
  "glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary"
  }
}
```

And this is my C#:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class GlossaryRoot
{
    public Glossary Glossary { get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
public class Glossary
{
    public string title { get; set; }
}


public class Data_Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
    
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Example.json");
        string dataAsJSON = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        var myData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GlossaryRoot>(dataAsJSON);

        string myTitle = myData.Glossary.title;

        Debug.Log(myTitle);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error:
"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? I've been looking for solutions, and tried a lot of things, but still with no success.

I know there are multiple issues similar to this one such as:
[C#, Unity3D, JSON Parsing: Failing to parse JSON into C# object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408545/c-unity3d-json-parsing-failing-to-parse-json-into-c-sharp-object)

But still I can't get it to work.
Even if I get delete the "gets and sets", I get "Null" in the console.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. You names don't match it should be `public Glossary glossary` instead.
2. afaik Unity's Serializer (and therefore also the builtin `JsonUtility`) doesn't support (de)serialization of properties, rather use fields

so this should work

```
    [Serializable]
    public class GlossaryRoot
    {
        public Glossary glossary;
    }


    [Serializable]
    public class Glossary
    {
        public string title;
    }
```